# Android Studio - Relative Layout on top of buttons have transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a `RelativeLayout` on the top of another containing `buttons` in order to *hide* the ones below.

I have set a black background to the top `RelativeLayout` however, the layout is till transparent showing the objects underneath. Also The `buttons` behind the top relative layout are still clickable.

My question is how can I use a `RelativeLayout` in order to hide another one containing object underneath? The top relative layout should be *NOT* transparent and the `buttons` underneath *not* clickable.

[image]

Comment: show us the layout

Comment: sorry .. Just added it. The buttons below the layout are still clickable and I cannot set the top layout not transparent

Comment: @SNos if you have two relatives make the second one Visibility gone when the top one appears

Comment: you always want it to happen?

Comment: can we see the  layout file?

Comment: the top layout should appear when The app is loading some data from url and disappear when done

Comment: post your code of `xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Your buttons go here -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/prompt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- your prompt -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and when you're done with your prompt relative layout, then from your activity say something like this:

```
View prompt = findeViewById(R.id.prompt);
prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and then visible your button layout

```
View buttonLayout = findeViewById(R.id.buttons);
buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I get the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: check for layout id

Comment: The layout ID are correct. I have setup them inside `onCreate`

Comment: you should setup your ids in xml files.

Comment: Also I get: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: all right, then you are trying to access that view from another thread or async task, am i right?

Comment: I wanted to call it at the start `onCreate` but it gives me always errors. So I am calling inside a method that I use to upload image to server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131596/discussion-between-xfighter-and-snos).